# How to add smtp settings using helm chart to prometheus-operator?

Tags: grafana, prometheus, kubernetes-helm, prometheus-operator

I am providing smtp configuration through values.yaml but the grafana not able to take this settings

Provided smtp configuration through values.yaml  like

```
{ 
"grafana.ini":{ 
     "smtp": {
     "enabled": true, 
     "host" : "smtp.mailtrap.io:25", 
     "user" : "username", 
     "password" : "password" 
             } 
              } 
}
```

used below cmd to install the charts

```
helm install stable/prometheus-operator --name prometheus-operator --namespace monitoring -f values.yaml
```

after updating values the grafana should be able to send email but i see http://localhost:3000/admin/settings is not updated with values provided from values.yaml file

Answer (score 0):

Referring to Grafna [chart](https://github.com/helm/charts/blob/master/stable/grafana/values.yaml#L377) you need:

```
# `existingSecret` is a reference to an existing secret containing the smtp configuration
```